# How to show and hide div elements using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is code where i tried to show and hide `div` elements using pure JavaScript.

Since when I click the button it take three clicks to hide the `div` elements and after that it run smoothly. I was trying to find how to show elements in first click.

```js
var count = 0;

function showMee() {
  var buttonHome = document.querySelector("#showMe");

  count += 1;
  buttonHome.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (count == 1) {
      document.querySelector('#linkMeOne').style.display = 'none';
      document.querySelector('#linkMeTwo').style.display = 'none';
    } else if (count == 2) {
      document.querySelector('#linkMeOne').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('#linkMeTwo').style.display = 'block';
      count = 0;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#linkMeOne {
  display: block;
}

#linkMeTwo {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="linkMeOne">
  Hiding me As first time....
</div>

<div id="linkMeTwo">
  Hiding me as well as...
</div>

<input type="button" value="Check Me" id="showMe" onclick="showMee()" />
```

Comment: second  "count = 0;" replce by  "count = 1;" (in showMe)

Comment: This is your code fixed and optimized: https://jsfiddle.net/6vcegj8u/

Comment: @ChrisG that code is very inefficient. Why not EITHER use the actual hidden attribute OR at least use `classList.toggle("hide",hidden)` now you are not even caching the style object.

Comment: @mplungjan Like I said, this is OP's code. My prime incentive here was to show how they went wrong in their own code. There's lots of other ways to do this.

Comment: Duplicate: [How to toggle CSS style on-click same button in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195789/how-to-toggle-css-style-on-click-same-button-in-js)

Comment: @ChrisG It was the "optimised" that got me there

Answer (score 1):

Just toggle hidden.

If you want them to start out hidden, add the hidden attribute to the divs

```js
const div1 = document.getElementById("linkMeOne");
const div2 = document.getElementById("linkMeTwo")
document.querySelector("#showMe").addEventListener("click",function() {
   div1.hidden = !div1.hidden;
   div2.hidden = !div2.hidden;
})
```

```html
<div id="linkMeOne">
  Hiding me As first time....
</div>

<div id="linkMeTwo">
  Hiding me as well as...
</div>

<input type="button" value="Check Me" id="showMe"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `addEventlistener` and the code will start working.

```js
var count = 0;

function showMee() {
  var buttonHome = document.querySelector("#showMe");

  count += 1;
  //buttonHome.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (count == 1) {
      document.querySelector('#linkMeOne').style.display = 'none';
      document.querySelector('#linkMeTwo').style.display = 'none';
    } else if (count == 2) {
      document.querySelector('#linkMeOne').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('#linkMeTwo').style.display = 'block';
      count = 0;
    }
  //});
}
```

```css
#linkMeOne {
  display: block;
}

#linkMeTwo {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="linkMeOne">
  Hiding me As first time....
</div>

<div id="linkMeTwo">
  Hiding me as well as...
</div>

<input type="button" value="Check Me" id="showMe" onclick="showMee()" />
```

Instead of using a variable, use a class to set the `display` to `none`.

```js
function showMee() {
  document.querySelector('#linkMeOne').classList.toggle('hidden');
  document.querySelector('#linkMeTwo').classList.toggle('hidden')
}
```

```css
#linkMeOne {
  display: block;
}

#linkMeTwo {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="linkMeOne">
  Hiding me As first time....
</div>

<div id="linkMeTwo">
  Hiding me as well as...
</div>

<input type="button" value="Check Me" id="showMe" onclick="showMee()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are many correct answers, all of them lack simplicity.
The easiest of all solution is to add an `eventListener` to the button and toggle a class to all elements with a certain class. That way you don't have to list every single element:

```js
document.querySelector('#showMe').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.linkMe').forEach(el =>
    el.classList.toggle('d-block')
  );
})
```

```css
.linkMe {
  display: none;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkMe">
  Hiding me As first time....
</div>

<div class="linkMe">
  Hiding me as well as...
</div>

<input type="button" value="Check Me" id="showMe" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just toggle using a data attribute and some CSS.  Here is a verbose version of that:

```js
document.querySelector("#showMe")
  .addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const t = event.target;
    const showem = t.dataset.show;
    document.querySelectorAll('.can-toggle').forEach((element) => {
      element.dataset.show = showem;
    });
    t.dataset.show = showem == "show" ? "hide" : "show";
  });
```

```css
.can-toggle[data-show="hide"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="can-toggle">
  Hiding me As first time....
</div>

<div class="can-toggle">
  Hiding me as well as...
</div>

<input type="button" value="Check Me" id="showMe" data-show="hide" />
```

OR even independently with an initial state:

```js
document.querySelector("#showMe")
  .addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.can-toggle').forEach((element) => {
      element.dataset.show = element.dataset.show == "hide" ? "show" : "hide";
    });
  });
```

```css
.can-toggle[data-show="hide"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="can-toggle" data-show="hide">
  Hiding me As first time....
</div>
<div class="can-toggle">
  Hiding me as well as...
</div>
<div class="can-toggle" data-show="Ishow">
  What am I?
</div>

<input type="button" value="Check Me" id="showMe" data-show="hide" />
```